CPANEL Run Node.js App: Fatal process out of memory: Failed to reserve memory for Isolate V8 pointer compression cage
I've tried running the code on local, it doesnt even take 1GB of RAM, why when i tried running it on cpanel it is asking for v8 is it indicates it need 8GB?
(Node.js version 18.20.4, application mode production)
->> issue: using package-> Tiktoken to calculate openai token ?
I have set the package.json:
"start:prod": "node --max-old-space-size=2048 dist/main.js",
"start:prod": "node --max-old-space-size=1024 dist/main.js",
"start:prod": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 dist/main.js",

nothing work.
returncode: -5
stdout:

stderr:
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal process out of memory: Failed to reserve memory for Isolate V8 pointer compression cage
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7fff2228c610
 1: 0x7f1615e62e49  [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 2: 0x7f1616dc082d V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 3: 0x7f16165044d9  [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 4: 0x7f16167aeb22 v8::internal::IsolateAllocator::IsolateAllocator() [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 5: 0x7f161666bd77 v8::internal::Isolate::Allocate(bool) [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 6: 0x7f1615d0ae04 node::NewIsolate(v8::Isolate::CreateParams*, uv_loop_s*, node::MultiIsolatePlatform*, bool) [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 7: 0x7f1615e36fbe node::NodeMainInstance::NodeMainInstance(node::SnapshotData const*, uv_loop_s*, node::MultiIsolatePlatform*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&) [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 8: 0x7f1615d975d3 node::LoadSnapshotDataAndRun(node::SnapshotData const**, node::InitializationResult const*) [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
 9: 0x7f1615d9b2fe node::Start(int, char**) [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/../lib/libnode.so.108]
10: 0x7f1614229590  [/lib64/libc.so.6]
11: 0x7f1614229640 __libc_start_main [/lib64/libc.so.6]
12: 0x402035 _start [/opt/alt/alt-nodejs18/root/usr/bin/node]

Out of memory error may be caused by hitting LVE limits
or "Max data size", "Max address space" or "Max resident set" process limits
Please check LVE limits and process limits. Readjust them if necessary
More info: https://docs.cloudlinux.com/shared/cloudlinux_os_components/#known-restrictions-and-issues

process limits "/proc/1391670/limits":
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    0                    bytes     
Max resident set          4294967296           4294967296           bytes     
Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes 
Max open files            1073741816           1073741816           files     
Max locked memory         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max address space         4294967296           4294967296           bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       unlimited            unlimited            signals   
Max msgqueue size         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max nice priority         unlimited            unlimited            
Max realtime priority     unlimited            unlimited            
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        

